# Auto-correct on my iMac is checked so why is it not working in Apple Mail?

Tags: keyboard, imac, autocorrect

"Correct Spelling Automatically" box is checked in Keyboard settings.
"Check Spelling As I Type" is checked in in Mail preferences.

With the proper boxes checked, why is iMac Mail not correcting misspellings in emails? Auto-correct is working in Safari when I type this post. On my Macbook Air I am getting autocorrect when typing up emails. On my iPhone it is working. Why not on iMac Mail? Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You also need 'Correct Spelling Automatically' set in Mail. It's not global.

Comment: Where are you finding that setting? I only see "check spelling automatically as I type."

Comment: (In Mail itself) ... Edit > Spelling & Grammar >

Comment: Thx. For some reason that option is greyed out and not available to me.

Comment: It's only available when you have an email open that you're about to send